# Get objectGUID and objectSid for Active Directory user

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

I can see what the objectGUID and objectSid are for a user, by going to: Active Directory Users and Computers -> *The User* -> Properties -> Attribute Editor, but it won't let me actually copy the values in string format! I can't even really copy the Hexadecimal value and convert it online since the hex characters are not given in order.

I've tried using ldp.exe but I can't get it to find the user.

Are there any other tricks to getting (and copying!) the objectGUID and objectSid of an Active Directory user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is PowerShell an option? If so you can do something along the following.

`Get-ADUser USERNAME -Properties * | Select SamaccountName,ObjectSid,ObjectGUID`

Comment: Thanks, I used `Get-ADUser USERNAME` to get the information (splitting the Properties up cut off the ends of the values).

Comment: You can generally do a `| -select -expand SOMETHING` and get the item alone.

Comment: Thanks! is `objectGUID` different from `objectId` that is returned in the `Get-MsolUser` cmdlet?

Comment: @asgs That looks like a 365 command which I don't have access to so can't help sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For all user user below powershell command and get it in csv

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=USA Users,DC=yourdomain,DC=net"  | Export-csv -path C:\usersproprieties.csv
```